# instalation process error

Tags: system-installation

I have able to install Ubuntu on my PC.
Everything goes fine till, copying file dialogue box pops up., after coping for a while error shows up. It says old disk, or old DVD or keep PC in cool place. I have tried it all. Tried reinstalling Ubuntu 14.4 over and over.  Every time it shows the error at the same place .I.e. While coping file,It shows the following "(errno 5) input/output error". Pls help.

Pls note. : I have also lost 40 GB of space in my hard disk

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same place, you probably have a corrupt DVD/CD & it's failing to copy something due to that. You can burn a new one, but I would check the 'checksum' (.md5) files for the .ISO you have first, to ensure your download was good. The website you got it from should explain that.

A missing 40GB is probably related to partitioning, but you need to tell us more about that bit - perhaps get the install done first, it may well not be a problem.

Comment: I have downloaded Ubuntu from its official website. I am on win-xp and I used Nero to burn .iso disc. maybe DVD must be corrupted. thanks I'll burn a new one. 
thanks have a nice day.

Comment: How to check that download was good? I am a windows user ,new to Linux and I have no technical knowledge.

Comment: Go to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) & look for "Verifying the ISO integrity" - this section has a bunch of links to guides.